# Cómo renderizar un array dentro de otro array agrupado con Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy trabajando con Laravel Vuejs, y desde mi base de datos obtengo un array de objeto llamado `arrayServicio`, a través de axios realizo un get donde se puede ver representado el array que obtengo.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
  //this.traerServicio()
  },
  data() {
    return {
    arrayServicio: [
        { servicio: '2', formato: '[".mp3",".mp4"]' },
        { servicio: '3', formato: '[".jpg",".png"]' },
      ],
    arrayFormato: [".mp3",".mp4",".jpg",".png"]
    }
  },
  methods:
  {
    traerServicio() { 
      axios.get('/').then(function(response){
        this.arrayServicio = response.data

        /*LO QUE OBTENGO DESDE LA BASE DE DATOS 
       arrayServicio: [
          { servicio: '2', formato: '[".mp3",".mp4"]' },
          { servicio: '3', formato: '[".jpg",".png"]' },
        ]
       */
          $.each(response.data, function (key,value) {
            $.each(JSON.parse( value.formato ), (key,element) => { 
               this.arrayFormato.push(element)
               
        /*LO QUE OBTENGO SERÍA:
       arrayFormato: [
          { '[".mp3",".mp4",".jpg",".png"]' }
        ]
       */  
               
               
               
            })
         })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <div>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h5>Forma Incorrecta:</h5><small>Así lo tengo de momento</small>
           <div v-for="servicio in arrayServicio"  :key="servicio.id">
             <strong>Id Servicio:</strong> {{servicio.servicio}}
             <br>
             <strong>Formato:</strong>
             <div v-for="formato in arrayFormato" :key="formato.id">
                {{formato}}
             </div>
           </div>
            
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h5>Forma Correcta:</h5>
             <strong>Id Servicio:</strong> 2
             <br>
             <strong>Formato:</strong>
             <br>
             .mp3
             <br>
             .mp4
             <br>
             <strong>Id Servicio:</strong> 3
             <br>
             <strong>Formato:</strong>
             <br>
             .jpg
             <br>
             .png
           <br>
         </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br><br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
       <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Una vez almaceno ese array, lo que realizo es realizar un `Parse`, dentro del atributo formato, ya que ahí se encuentra otro array con los formatos de cada servicio. (ver comentarios).

Al realizar este `Parseo`, finalmente realizo un push para almacenar todos estos elementos (formatos) en un array llamado `arrayFormato`.

El problema que estoy teniendo que al realizar ese push, me almacena todo en conjunto, y no es lo que busco.

Lo que estoy buscando es almacenar cada formato, respecto a su servicio.

En la vista de HTML intenté mostrar el resultado correcto, pero la idea es armar todo esto con `VueJS`.

Comment: Proba cambiar esto: <div v-for="formato in arrayFormato" :key="formato.id"> por esto <div v-for="formato in servicio" :key="formato.id">.. y decime que pasa...

Comment: me lo agrupa por servicio, pero me lo sigue trayendo como un array. https://jsfiddle.net/p2m4ft9u/

Comment: esto: '[".jpg",".png"]' es un string.. seguro que tu back te devuelve una cadena? si es asi, vas  a tener que dividirla para ontener cada elemento como un objeto

Comment: Sí, está como string la parte comentada, pero si notas en el ejemplo, lo estoy considerando como un array, (la definición de formato en arrayServicio), aún así no me funciona.

Comment: (lo cambié en el jsfiddle y aún así no funciona) https://jsfiddle.net/xzhcdm39/

Comment: fijate en la documentacion de v-for... va contra un objeto, no contra un array....

Comment: En el caso que lo traiga como cadena, cómo puedo dividirlo para obtener cada elemento ?

Comment: Formato deberia ser un array de objetos.. y ahi si vas a poder acceder a cada uno... pero esa seria otra pregunta totalmente distinta... porque no haces que tu back ya te solucione ese problema?